# Java Regex amount of characters in one group determines the number of characters in next group

Tags: java, regex, conditional-statements

Here's one for you. Is it possible to conditionally match the number of characters in one group based on the number of characters already matched in a previous group.

I need to match something like this

```
ABCDEFG | .ABCDEF | ..ABCDE | ...ABCD | ....ABC | .....AB
```

I know that this can be done with multiple OR statements capturing each group individually like this:

```
[A-Z0-9]{7}|\.[A-Z0-9]{6}|\.{2}[A-Z0-9]{5}        you get the idea
```

but can this be done with conditional matching? (Yes I know that I only listed characters; that was for clarity but I need to match numbers as well hence the regex expression). Also tried this but that doesn't quite work.

```
(\.*[A-Z0-9]*){7}
```

Comment: in this particular case may be `((?![A-Z0-9]\.)[.A-Z0-9]){7}` [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/skNmeU/1) to match a sequence of 7 character among [.A-Z0-9] where a character is never followed by a dot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a single capturing group, perhaps you could make use of the `\G` anchor to assert the position at the end of the previous match:

```
(?:\.*([A-Z0-9]+)|\G(?!\A))(?:\h+\|\h+|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FVhZYM/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Z18FDa)

For example if you only want to get the value of the capturing group:

```
String regex = "(?:\\.*([A-Z0-9]+)|\\G(?!\\A))(?:\\h+\\|\\h+|$)";
String string = "ABCDEFG | .ABCDEF | ..ABCDE | ...ABCD | ....ABC | .....AB";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
ABCDEFG
ABCDEF
ABCDE
ABCD
ABC
AB
```